# Monitorar atividades do Mysql server

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho um sistema (php e mysql) hospedado em rede aqui na empresa, instalado em várias estações. Gostaria de saber se existe algum comando ou ferramenta para monitoramento das solicitações (queryes) para feitas para o servidor  MYSQL? Algo semelhante ao Profiler do SQLSERVER. 
Algo que mostre selects, updates, etc, que o sistema faz no servidor mysql em tempo real. Obrigado!